# i want to create an empty array to fill it later

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi guys i tryed to create an empty array to fill it later. I post my code so you can help me. XD

```
"use strict"
var array = new array(6);
 for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    do {
        var number = prompt("Put the element" + (i+1), 0);
    }while(isNaN(number));
    arr.push(number);
 };

write.data(array);
```

Comment: `array` ≠ `Array`.

Comment: var array = [] , it creates an empty array.

Comment: `arr.push` - there is no `arr`

Comment: Javascript does not have fixed-length arrays. The length is always dynamic. `new Array(6)` creates this array: `[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]`. If you now push let's say `1` to that array it becomes `[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1 ]` which I assume is not what you want.

Comment: thank you im a noob with javascript. I really apreciate your contribution thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may have copy and pasted some code without understanding what it is doing. 
You are trying to push to an array, but you've declared your array as array, but trying to push to arr. Which is why it's not working.

```
var arr = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    arr.push(i + 1);
 }

console.log(arr);
alert(arr);
```

EDIT * You actually don't even need to declare the new Array(6), you can just use new Array() to push. However, if you would like to declare the size, you can do this instead.

```
var arr = new Array(6);
     for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        arr[i] = i + 1;
     }

    console.log(arr);
    alert(arr);
```

Comment: hank you im a noob with javascript. I really apreciate your contribution thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
var a = new Array(6);
for(var i = 0;i < 6;i++){
     a.push(i+1);
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: You can declare your incremental value inside the FOR loop. e.g. for(var  i = 0; i < 6; i++), so there is no need to declare it outside the loop if it isn't being used elsewhere.

Comment: but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: It is more readable.

Comment: Ok. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
var arr = []; // create an empty object
for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
   arr.push(i + 1); // fill the object
}

console.log(arr);
alert(arr); // shows 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

This does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you im a noob with javascript. I really apreciate your contribution thanks!

Comment: Please accept if you think this was the most helpful